# useSpring() doesn't work when animating transform with initial state equal to "translate3d(0,0,0)"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-spring

How to use the useSpring() hook?

I'm trying to use the useSpring() hook to animate the transform property:

It simply doesn't work if the initial state is `"translate3d(0,0,0)"`, for instance, if I initialise it like that with `toggle` being `false`:

```
const props = useSpring({
  transform: toggle ? "translate3d(0,-25px,0)" : "translate3d(0,0,0)"
});
```

This, on the other hand, works:

```
const props = useSpring({
  transform: toggle ? "translate3d(0,-25px,0)" : "translate3d(0,1px,0)"
});
```

Is this a bug?
  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to explicitly indicate `unit` of change. Like `pixel` or `percentage`. Try this:

```
const props = useSpring({
  transform: toggle ? "translate3d(0,-25px,0)" : "translate3d(0,0px,0)"
});
```